# What is the advantage of using constructor injection in a repository in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5, repository-pattern

I am building a laravel 5 app and I have a repository like below:

```
use App\Unit

class UnitRepository implements IUnitRepository
{
     public function get_all_units()
    {
        return Unit::all();
    }

    // More methods below
}
```

In about 6 methods in the repository, I am doing something like 
Unit::someMethod. Now I am wondering if I should use constructor 
injection like so

```
class UnitRepository implements IUnitRepository
{
    public function __construct(Unit $unit){ 
        $this->unit = $unit
    }

    public function get_all_units()
    {
        return $this->unit->all();
    }

    // More methods below
}
```

So what would be the advantage of using constructor injection in my case. Is they some
kind of performance improvement considering that I am using the facade in about 6 methods?

Appreciate help

Comment: It depends.  Is it possible multiple implementations of User could exist?  If so DI might be beneficial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not just a matter of performance (btw: the difference in terms of performance of the two cases is negligible).

As your `Unit` model is going to be accessed in almost any method of the repository, using constructor injection is a clear way to explicit the direct dependency of your repository to the `Unit` class

Besides, if you inject the dependency in you constructor, and in future you'll change the `Unit` class, all you have to do is to change the constructor's parameter. Instead, using facades, you'd have to change all the facades calls in all of your methods